# Where is the files.pythonhosted.org API docs?

Tags: python

Where is the documentation for files.pythonhosted.org's API? I've tried finding it, but I instead found a bunch of documentation of other stuff hosted on pythonhosted.org. I need the API for pythonhosted.org, not PyPI.

Comment: are you searching for `pypi api`?

Answer (score 0):

They can be found in [warehouse.pypa.io’s integration guide](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/integration-guide.html#predictable-urls):

> Predictable URLs
>
> You can use our conveyor service to fetch this file, which exists for
> cases where using the API is impractical or impossible. This is for
> example the case for Linux package maintainers, as package build
> scripts or package metadata expect static URLs in some cases.
>
> URLs can be constructed as follows, with wheel file names following
> [PEP 491#file-name-convention](https://peps.python.org/pep-0491/#file-name-convention).
>
> ```py
> host = 'https://files.pythonhosted.org'
>
> def source_url(name, version):
>     return f'{host}/packages/source/{name[0]}/{name}/{name}-{version}.tar.gz'
>
> def wheel_url(name, version, build_tag, python_tag, abi_tag,
> platform_tag):
>     # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/#file-name-convention
>     wheel_parts = {
>         tag: re.sub('[^\w\d.]+', '_', part, re.UNICODE)
>         for tag, part in locals().items()
>     }
>     wheel_parts['optional_build_tag'] = f'-{wheel_parts["build_tag"]}' if build_tag else ''
>     filename = '{name}-{version}{optional_build_tag}-{python_tag}-{abi_tag}-{platform_tag}.whl'\
>                .format_map(wheel_parts)
>     return f'{host}/packages/{python_tag}/{name[0]}/{name}/{filename}'
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The api reference documentation is available [here](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/).

API endpoint:

```
https://pypi.org/pypi/
```

You can search the package docs like:

```
https://pypi.org/pypi/numpy/json
```